# WinRT app with bing translator

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, bing-api, microsoft-translator

I want to use the bing translator in my WinRT app. Found some sample code here: http://codepaste.net/hgrb91, but I get an error with the code 400, because of a bad request.

What can I do?

Comment: Could you post some code? Where exactly do you receive error 400? Does the same code work for you in a desktop app?

Comment: You can find the whole code on the website I've mentioned in my question. The error war in this method: public async Task<Token> GetTokenAsync(). I didn't try the code in a desktop app.

Comment: Where in that code you get error, I guess `TranslateAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get your own `ClientID` and `ClientSecret`, and put them in the code? Without them properly set up, you'll get an error 400.

See the blog post here for details on how to get them:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted1.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own ClientID and my own ClientSecret directly from the website of azure.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this from time to time, and the answer is usually to do with a registration issue for the app or for the API.

- Visit https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications -- Is your app listed here? If so, use the Client ID and Client Secret for this entry, and not the account-wide Client ID that you got when you signed up for Azure. If not, register one from this screen, and use its Client ID and Client Secret.
- Visit https://datamarket.azure.com/account/datasets -- Is Microsoft Translator listed here as a service that you have subscribed to? Is it Active? Do you have enough characters left in your subscription?